# How to display the progress bar for 15 seconds in swt

Tags: java, swt

Am newer for SWT..  I have to write a method for displaying progress bar. if i cal the method. i should      pass time and bounds as a parameter for the method.

```
    package ProgressViewer;
    import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
    import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ProgressBar;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

    public class PBMethod 
    {
        private static Shell shell;

        public static void Pv7( Shell shell2,final int num,final int xA,final int xB,final int xH,final int xW) 
        {
            shell=shell2;

            final ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(shell, SWT.NONE);
            bar.setSize(1500, 1000);    

            shell.setLayout(new GridLayout()); 
            shell.setSize(1500, 1000);

            final Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                public void run() 
                {   
                    for(int i=0; i<=num; i++) 
                    {
                        final int value = i;
                        try 
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(50);       
                        } 
                        catch (Exception e){}
                        shell.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                bar.setBounds(xA,xB,xH,xW);
                                bar.setSelection(value);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    shell.getDisplay().syncExec(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            bar.dispose();
                            MessageBox dialog1 = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.NONE| SWT.OK| SWT.CANCEL);
                            dialog1.setText("Information");
                            dialog1.setMessage("Saved Successfully");
                            dialog1.open(); 
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            thread.start();
        }
    }
```

Here this above method is passing bounds and percentage of .. but not the time.. Progress bar should display for 10seconds.. or 15 seconds.. that i should give in parameter only..

But in the code sent the second parameter is used for the percentage of completion of the progress bar.
A parameter should be passed for the time the progress viewer is to be displayed, e.g. 10 for 10 seconds. If we want to change it to 15, there should be a change in the parameter value only..

Help would appreciate!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Progress Bar is built to show the progress of task and a task completion time always varies, Therefore there is no such method which takes time as parameter.
Even if you find a way to do so, it is never a good practice.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @ Jprogrammer